# how to extract and combine features from speech?

Tags: audio, feature-extraction, feature-selection, speech

I am working on speech emotion recognition, what is the best way to extract features like MFCC, PLP, LPCC, Pitch, shimmer ... and combine them, does anyone have an idea? thanks in advance!